# Why double has specific range of values? (Java)

Tags: java, double

Why double in Java has a specific range of values from `±5,0*10(^-324)` to `±1,7*10(^308)`? I mean why it's not like `±5,0*10(^-324)` to `±5,0*10(^308)` or `±1,7*10(^-324)` to `±1,7*10(^308)`?

Comment: Because that is how IEEE-754 is specified: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: If it didn't have a specific range, then `double` would be impossible to represent.  (You can't represent indefinitely large numbers with bounded memory.)

Comment: Look at my answer, it took some time to dig it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question is subnormal numbers, check following link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Double floating point numbers in Java are based on the format defined in `IEEE 754`.

See this link for the explanation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Following is a simple set of rules

1. Floating point number is represented in `64 bits`
2. 64 bits are divided in following

   1. Sign bit: `1 bit` (sign of the number)
   2. Exponent: `11 bits` (signed)
   3. Significand precision (Fraction): `52 bits`

[image: double bits]

Number range that we get from this setup is

```
-1022 <= Exponent <= 1023 (total 2046) (excluding 0 and 2047, they have special meanings)


000 (0 in base 16) is used to represent a signed zero (if F=0) and subnormals (if F≠0); and
7ff (2047 in base 16) is used to represent ∞ (if F=0) and NaNs (if F≠0),
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias

and

```
-2^52 <= Fraction <= 2^52
```

So the minimum and maximum numbers that can be represented are

```
Min positive double = +1 * 2^(-1022) ≈ 2.225 * 10(−308)
Note: 1022 * Math.log(2) / Math.log(10) = 307.652
      and Math.pow(10, 1 - .652) = 2.228 (.652 is approximation)

Max positive double = +(2^52) * (2^1023) = 1.797 * 10^308
```

So the range becomes **[-2.225 * 10(−308), 1.797 * 10^308]**

This range changes due to [subnormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)

> Subnormal number is a number that is smaller than the minimum normal
>   number defined by the specification.

If I have a number `0.00123` it would be represented as `1.23 * 10^(-3)`. Floating point numbers by specification don't have leading zeroes. So If there's a number with leading zeros, it adds to the default `Exponent`. So If I have a number with minimum exponent possible with leading zeroes, leading zeros will add to the negative exponent.

There are `52` bits for the `signifand (fraction)` so maximum number of leading zeros in binary can be `51`. which effectively produce following number.

```
Min positive Subnormal = 1 * 2^-52 * (2^-1022) = 2^(-2074) ≈ 4.9·10^(−324)

Note: 1074 * Math.log(2) / Math.log(10) = 323.306
      Math.pow(10, 1 - 0.306) = 4.943
```

So there you have it, range is now

**[- Min subnormal number, + Max normal number]**

or

**[- 4.9 * 10^(−324), + 1.79769 *10^308]**